# Ansible always run role

Tags: ansible

I'm searching for a way to always run a role, regardless of `--tags` args.

Here is a simple playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - { role: role1, tags: always },
    - { role: role2, tags: tag1 },
    - { role: role3, tags: tag2 }
```

I would like only `role1` and `role2` to run when I launch the following filter (instead of only `role2`):

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts deploy.yml --tags tag1
```

I though it was the default behavior with the special `always` tag (see http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags)

I'm playing with Ansible 1.8.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your Ansible version is the problem.

The `always` tag was introduced with [this pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/10183), which was merged into the devel branch on February 25. According to the [releases](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/releases?after=v1.9.1-0.4.rc4), the next released version after that date was Ansible 1.9.0-1.